# How to add files in .xip using command line prompt or MSBuild Script?

Tags: cmd, msbuild

I have some file in a folder. And I want all files from the folder to be packaged in .xip file.

Comment: XIP was an Apple product which has been removed from public use. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242948/what-is-the-format-of-a-xip-file The tags on this question indicate a Microsoft Windows system. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @lit I have a utility which used to archive binary files in a package of .xip file. But now we want it to archive using MSBuild Script or Command Line Script.    For example we have file1.txt and file2.txt....we used archive them in files.xip, which send to clinet. And client used to extract it.

Comment: Do you have documentation for the utility? What does the documentation say about creating a .xip archive? Does the utility run on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: @lit Sorry, I don't have documentation for the utlity. And yes it is working on MS Window 7.  utility is compressing the file using gZip and package in .xip file. Anyway, now I am waiting for the code of utlity. And will let you people know once I got he solution. Thanks !!!